# Deploying to Heroku: Module not found (not case-sensitive issue)

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, import

I'm trying to deploy an app that was created with create-react-app. 
The app works both as *npm start* and *npm run build* locally, but gives a module not found error for my ActionCreators when deployed to Heroku:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJ0SX.jpg)

Case sensitivity is not an issue, I have checked, as that is usually the error. I have also put the devDependencies under dependencies as that was another error I had.

My action creator are exported as:

```
 export const newProjectCreated = newProject => ({
  type: 'PROJECT_CREATED',
  newProject
});

export const projectDeleted = deletedProject => ({
  type: 'PROJECT_DELETED',
  deletedProject
});
```

and imported as

```
import * as ActionCreators from '../Actions/ActionCreators';
```

Can it be that Heroku doesn't like this kind of import? What else could be going wrong?

I am grateful for any input!

Comment: You need babel to convert the es6 syntax. See: https://gist.github.com/bitgord/245535acdfb39f489913c1cf3e6fe6af

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have Babel installed and I have searched for the ES-2015: https://imgur.com/a/3VDuI and it seems to be configured. Does this look correct?

Comment: Have you followed that gist. You've to use the code generated/compiled by babel.

`babel app/*.js -d dist` This will compile your code in app directory to dist directory, which you can execute.

Comment: Nevermind. If you've used the create-react-app tool then it's preconfigured.  Try this then : https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack Will make your life easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer:

It WAS a case-sensitive issue. The problem is that I didn't know that GIT is not looking for case-sensitive changes in the file.

While I was debugging I cleaned up the document and capitalized one file, so that everything is consistent. My project-tree showed a changed file but the git I was pushing was still the one with a small letter.

Comment: nice one...we should stop using camel case folder names

Answer (score 2):

Just been stung by this same issue. Mac filesystem and git apparently not case sensitive, I had to run the following on each controversial file and folder:

```
git mv foldername tempname && git mv tempname folderName
```