# Error while deploying Spring boot app to Heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

I have an issue while deploying my Spring boot app to Heroku.

- I am trying to deploy it as a java app instead of building and deploying a jar file.
- I have used the free Postgresql in Heroku.

The error while pushing the app to Heroku master is:

```
remote:        [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
remote:        [INFO] Compiling 18 source files to /tmp/build_79201803/target/classes
remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_79201803/src/main/java/com/pukitbanta/springblog/model/post.java:[15,8] class Post is public, should be declared in a file named Post.java
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_79201803/src/main/java/com/pukitbanta/springblog/model/user.java:[12,8] class User is public, should be declared in a file named User.java
remote:        [INFO] 2 errors
remote:        [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  16.300 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-11T11:09:38Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project springblog: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_79201803/src/main/java/com/pukitbanta/springblog/model/post.java:[15,8] class Post is public, should be declared in a file named Post.java
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_79201803/src/main/java/com/pukitbanta/springblog/model/user.java:[12,8] class User is public, should be declared in a file named User.java
remote:        [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
```

The error here specifies that my `User` and `Post` models file name starts with lowercase letters.

But my file structure is:

[image: File Structure for the models]

I do not think the error is in the Models, and I am not able to find out the issue.

Comment: Can you share the content of the files? (Post/User.java)

Comment: It was not an issue about the content of Post/User but the files stored in GitHub was in lower case. So, I just updated the file name with `core.ignorecase` to `false` and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot, the file name starts with a capital letter, but

```
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_79201803/src/main/java/com/pukitbanta/springblog/model/post.java:[15,8] class Post is public, should be declared in a file named Post.java
remote:        [ERROR] /tmp/build_79201803/src/main/java/com/pukitbanta/springblog/model/user.java:[12,8] class User is public, should be declared in a file named User.java
```

the file name displayed in the error message is in lower case.

Please check again for lowercase letters. If they are in lowercase, please correct them as follows:

- Rename `post.java` to `Post.java`
- Rename `user.java` to `User.java`

If it doesn't make sense to rename those files, it's probably a problem with your Git settings.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46670520/1979953

> It WAS a case-sensitive issue. The problem is that I didn't know that GIT is not looking for case-sensitive changes in the file.

You can check your git configuration:

```
$ git config -l | grep ignorecase
```

The `core.ignorecase` is the one we need this time.

If `core.ignorecase` is `true`, Git will ignore case differences; if `false`, Git will recognize the difference. So you need to set `false`.

Then let Git recognize the changes and deploy them to Heroku again.

To update the core.ignorecase to either `true` or `false` run:

`git config core.ignorecase true`

or

`git config core.ignorecase false`.

Comment: hey thanks, I updated the core.ignorecase to false and it fixed my issue

Answer (score 3):

I solved mine by changing java version 11 to 8(In pom.xml).

From:

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
```

To:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

- Put this in the `pom.xml`.
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Pom Changed"`
- `git push heroku master`