# React-Why does heroku not recognize my "models" folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I want to deploy my app to heroku, but as always there are errors. This time I can't figure out what the problem is. I hope that some of you can help me. It can't find some files like my models/User file, but i just can't figure out why.

here is my heroku logs --tail log:

```
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332352+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332393+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332394+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332394+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332395+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/User'
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332395+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332395+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/controllers/authController.js
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332396+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/routes/auth.js
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332396+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/routes/index.js
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332397+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/index.js
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332404+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1030:15)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332405+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:27)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332406+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:19)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332406+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332406+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/controllers/authController.js:3:14)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332407+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332407+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332407+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332408+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332408+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:19)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332408+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332409+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/routes/auth.js:9:5)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332409+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332409+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332410+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332410+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14) {
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332410+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332410+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332411+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/controllers/authController.js',
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332411+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/routes/auth.js',
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332412+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/routes/index.js',
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332412+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/index.js'
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332412+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-08-13T10:52:56.332412+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-08-13T10:52:56.341133+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-13T10:52:56.341538+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-08-13T10:52:56.342556+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! softuni-react-gamingarts@1.0.0 start: `cd server && node index.js`
2020-08-13T10:52:56.342757+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-08-13T10:52:56.342939+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-08-13T10:52:56.343025+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the softuni-react-gamingarts@1.0.0 start script.
2020-08-13T10:52:56.343097+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-13T10:52:56.350212+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-13T10:52:56.350394+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-13T10:52:56.350469+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-08-13T10_52_56_343Z-debug.log
2020-08-13T10:52:56.400429+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-13T10:52:56.441366+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-13T10:52:56.443848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-08-13T10:53:16.623284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-08-13T10:53:21.942790+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-13T10:53:21.942812+00:00 app[web.1]: > softuni-react-gamingarts@1.0.0 start /app
2020-08-13T10:53:21.942812+00:00 app[web.1]: > cd server && node index.js
2020-08-13T10:53:21.942813+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935440+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1033
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935486+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935487+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935487+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935488+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/User'
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935488+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935489+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/controllers/authController.js
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935489+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/routes/auth.js
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935490+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/routes/index.js
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935490+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server/index.js
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935491+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1030:15)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935491+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:27)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935492+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:19)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935492+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935493+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/controllers/authController.js:3:14)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935493+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935493+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935494+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935494+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935495+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:19)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935495+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:75:18)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935495+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/server/routes/auth.js:9:5)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935496+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1201:30)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935496+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1221:10)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935496+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1050:32)
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935497+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:938:14) {
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935497+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935497+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935498+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/controllers/authController.js',
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935498+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/routes/auth.js',
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935498+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/routes/index.js',
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935499+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/server/index.js'
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935499+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2020-08-13T10:53:22.935499+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-08-13T10:53:22.973818+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-08-13T10:53:22.974439+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-08-13T10:53:22.985453+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! softuni-react-gamingarts@1.0.0 start: `cd server && node index.js`
2020-08-13T10:53:22.986433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-08-13T10:53:22.986725+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-08-13T10:53:22.986943+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the softuni-react-gamingarts@1.0.0 start script.
2020-08-13T10:53:22.987322+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-08-13T10:53:23.007937+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-08-13T10:53:23.008291+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-08-13T10:53:23.008657+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-08-13T10_53_22_989Z-debug.log
2020-08-13T10:53:23.086999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-08-13T10:53:23.135813+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-08-13T10:54:07.983291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gamingartsreact.herokuapp.com request_id=298a36bc-eeab-4a66-94e5-2d320c381119 fwd="93.183.161.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-08-13T10:54:08.191444+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gamingartsreact.herokuapp.com request_id=2840511c-6251-4276-9ad3-73aa6a8efe6a fwd="93.183.161.162" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

My backend package.json

```
{
  "name": "softuni-react-gamingarts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.5.0",
    "npm": "6.14.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && npm run start",
    "server": "cd server && nodemon index.js",
    "backend": "cd server && nodemon index.js",
    "frontend": "cd client && npm run start",
    "app": "concurrently --names \"backend,frontend\" \"npm run backend --silent\" \"npm run frontend --silent\"",
    "start": "cd server && node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Dimitar Belchev",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cloudinary": "^1.22.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.1.3",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.6",
    "helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "heroku": "^7.42.6",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.6",
    "linkifyjs": "^2.1.9",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.28",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "validator": "^13.1.1"
  }
}
```

my file structure if it helps:  server folder, client folder(with package.json inside), package.json file for the server.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to see the folder structure as well as the code for the User model in order to help figure out the problem. As for the more obvious potential problems without seeing these details, I would check to make sure you exported your User model and double check the path to your routes. To me, it looks like either the '../models/User' file is not where the relative path expects it to be or that the file may not be visible due to export.

Comment: https://github.com/DimitarBelchev/gamingarts-softuni - the path towards models/user is server/models/user.js. everything works perfectly fine locally. Thank you for stopping by!

Comment: This may be a silly question, but did you at any point change the model/user.js file to model/User.js? The reason I ask is that another user had a module not found error in Heroku due to the fact that git does not track capitalization changes. Their file was correctly named locally but incorrect in git as a result. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585151/deploying-to-heroku-module-not-found-not-case-sensitive-issue

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same `Cannot find module '../models/something'` error while trying to deploy NextJS to Heroku. I had a folder called models with some JS files in it. Everything worked well while running locally, but Heroku didn't seem to like it.

All I did was **rename the models** folder to something else and it worked. Seems like theres some keywords that Heroku isn't fond of.